# LaTeX curly braces will not be passed. Have used Math quill and still not working

Tags: javascript, latex

I am using the Desmos API for a math project and am trying to set the latex of an expression to `f(x) = { x^2 : x > 1}` for piecemeal function. However, I cannot get the `{` or `}` within the latex. Function does not work without this character.

I have also used Mathquill for this equation to give me correct latex but even that (`f\left(x\right)=\left\{x^2:x>1\right\}`) does not work

I have been searching around stackoverflow and google for a while now. I have attempted `\{\}` , `\\left( \\right)` only provide `(` and `)`. Nothing will seem to work.

```html
<div id="calculator" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

```
var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);

calculator.setExpression({
    id:'1', 
    latex: "f(x)=\{x^2:x>1\}"
});
```

The curly braces are destroyed and the piecemeal function is not applied

This doesn't return any errors to my console. The only error is on the desmos calculator which says it doesnt understand why ":" is present (It would not do this if there was curly brackets specifying its the piecemeal function). The correct result should be
`f(x) = {x^2 : x > 1}`
but the actual result is
`f(x) = x^2 : x > 1`

Comment: Try `latex: "f(x)=\\{x^2:x>1\\}"` Probably to get a quote in a string, you need to double it.

Comment: This works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape the curly braces and you also have your [condition and value reversed](https://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/203192385-Piecewise). Here is a working snippet.

```js
var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);

calculator.setExpression({
    id:'1', 
    latex: "f(x)=\\left\\{x>1:x^2\\right\\}"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.3/calculator.js?apiKey=dcb31709b452b1cf9dc26972add0fda6"></script>
<div id="calculator" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how come the equation does not appear inside the expression. It is blank but the parabola is still shown

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the GraphingCalculator.

Comment: :/ as long as it does the job it should be fine

Comment: I found a fix to that by the way. Instead of just putting `\\}`, doing `\\left\\}` does the trick and won't cause that bug:
`f(x)= \\left\\{x = 2 : 2\\right\\}`

Comment: Nice! I'll update the answer if that's ok. Awesome find.